# How to query entire table using Room Library fts4 in android

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have Notes application written in Java. Here's main part of Room Database usage:

I have this Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface NoteDao {

    @Query("INSERT INTO notes (contents) VALUES ('new note')")
    void create();

    @Query("SELECT * from notes; ")
    List<Note> getAllNotes();

    @Query("UPDATE notes SET contents = :contents WHERE rowid = :id")
    void save(String contents, int id);

    @Query("DELETE from notes WHERE rowid = :id")
    void delete(int id);
}
```

Where getAllNotes() function is failing to compile and here's the error:
"The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [rowid] in com.sultanraja.notes.Note even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [contents]"

The Note class is as follows:

```
@Fts4
@Entity(tableName = "notes")
public class Note {
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    public int rowid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "contents")
    public String contents;

}
```

And the database is as follows:

```
@Database(entities = {Note.class}, version = 2, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class NotesDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract NoteDao NoteDao();
}
```

Before I have this version of the database I had a regular one not fts4 and everything was alright. after I changed the schema and used fts4 tables, the select * from table does not return all columns and compilation error happens. the question is why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot ORM map that one field. Try to annotate it properly:

```
@PrimaryKey
@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
public int rowid;
```

Or call it by it's expected name:

```
@PrimaryKey
@NonNull
public int id;
```

If in question, just open the database with an editor and see how the column is being called. Android Studio meanwhile even has such editor. Hint: per default SQLite calls it `_id`. SQLite command `.schema notes` would also show the table definition.

Comment: The problem is if I call it in any name other than rowid, I get the following compilation error: "The single primary key field in an FTS entity must either be named 'rowid' or must be annotated with @ColumnInfo(name = "rowid")"

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your query to (I know it's little bit strange, but it should work):

```
@Query("SELECT *, notes.rowid from notes")
List<Note> getAllNotes();
```

Comment: thanks, I think it might work, what did work is : @Query("SELECT *, rowid from notes")